# Atom Editor: Failed to spawn command ruby with .rbenv path

Tags: ruby, atom-editor, linter

I've installed Atom 1.18.0 x64 on my Windows 10. Then added `linter-ruby` package and edited this in my `config.cson` [as suggested here](https://atom.io/packages/linter-ruby):

```
"linter-ruby":
  ignoredExtensions: "erb, md"
  rubyExecutablePath: "/home/myusername/.rbenv/shims/ruby"
```

where the path correspods to `which ruby` (I have Bash on Ubuntu on Windows 10).

When I try to edit some Ruby file, I get this error:
`Error running Ruby Error: Failed to spawn command ruby. Make sure ruby is installed and on your PATH`

I've tried different paths, but nothing helps. I'm pretty sure, Ruby is installed on my machine as I can run my Rails app.

**How do I make my Atom linter to work, please? Thank you!**

**The solution**

I ended up uninstalling Atom completely and then installed `linter-ruby` with dependencies + installed Ruby in `C:\Ruby24-x64`. Then in `linter-ruby` settings left RubyExecutablePath as `Default: ruby`. Now it works.

Comment: Have you added `~/.rbenv/bin` to your path? I.e. is `export PATH="$HOME/.rbenv/bin:$PATH` in your `~/.bashrc`?

Comment: @Drenmi Yes, I have it there.